# Data not inserting into database using php

Tags: php, forms

I am using a form to insert data into a table I have created. I get no errors but for some reason, it states it worked, although it does not insert any data,

Here is what I'm using:

This is the form page:

```
<form name="myForm" action="submitform.php" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: 
<br />
<input type="text" name="fname" style="


Email:
<br />
<input type="email" name="email" >

Subject: 
<br />
<input type="text" name="subject">

Message: 
<br />
<textarea name="message" >
    </textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="add"  >
</form>
```

*phpsidecode*

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $submit=$_POST['add'];
    $Name=$_POST['fname'];
    $Email=$_POST['email'];
    $Subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $Message=$_POST['message'];
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbnmae='someuser';
    $dbpass='somepassword';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbnmae,$dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    $sql="INSERT INTO mydb(name, email, subject, message)VALUES('$Name', '$Email', '$Subject', '$Message')";
    mysql_select_db('project1');
    $retrieval=mysql_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$retrieval)
    {  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
        }
        echo"Entered data successfully\n";
         mysql_close($conn);
}else   
    {   echo"something went to wrong";

    }

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, please use `mysqli_*`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: `mysql_query($conn,$sql);` If you must use obsolete code look that one up in the manual

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: _I receive no errors_ Thats probably because you are not actually looking for any

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query is broken due to any single-comma character read from the POST vars. You should scape the variables using addslashes()

Anyway, as suggested in the comments, it's recommended to learn PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        $dbhost='localhost';
        $dbnmae='someuser';
        $dbpass='somepassword';
        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbnmae,$dbpass);
        if (!$conn) {
            die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error());
        }
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        $submit=$_POST['add'];
        $Name=$_POST['fname'];
        $Email=$_POST['email'];
        $Subject=$_POST['subject'];
        $Message=$_POST['message'];    
        $sql="INSERT INTO mydb(name, email, subject, message)VALUES('$Name', '$Email', '$Subject', '$Message')";
        mysqli_select_db('project1');
        $retrieval=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if(isset($retrieval)){  
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
             mysqli_close($conn);
            }           
    }else{  
     echo "something went to wrong";
 }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $Email=$_POST['email'];
    $Subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $Message=$_POST['message'];
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbnmae='someuser';
    $dbpass='somepassword';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbnmae,$dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('project1');
    $sql="INSERT INTO project1 VALUES('$Email', '$Subject', '$Message')";
    $retrieval=mysql_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$retrieval)
    {  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
        }
        echo"Entered data successfully\n";
         mysql_close($conn);
}
else   
{   echo"something went to wrong";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sunt add addshlashes to POST vars, look

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    $submit=($_POST['add']);
    $Name=addslashes($_POST['fname']);
    $Email=addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $Subject=addslashes($_POST['subject']);
    $Message=addslashes($_POST['message']);
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbnmae='someuser';
    $dbpass='somepassword';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbnmae,$dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    $sql="INSERT INTO mydb(name, email, subject, message)VALUES('$Name', '$Email', '$Subject', '$Message')";
    mysql_select_db('project1');
    $retrieval=mysql_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$retrieval)
    {  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
        }
        echo"Entered data successfully\n";
         mysql_close($conn);
}else   
    {   echo"something went to wrong";

    }

?>
```

for me this code work and after you put the code you need to delete the table and remake a new one. Hope it works for you